# What is the use case of Promise.resolve(promise)?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

We can call `Promise.resolve(value)` as well as `Promise.resolve(promise)`. I can understand where and how I should use the first call but am not sure about the second one.

Why not simply use the promise as argument in the first place? I mean calling:

> promise1.then()

instead of:

> Promise.resolve(promise1).then()

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` is basically "I don't care what this is, give me a promise". Generally, whenever you get an argument that *might* be a promise `Promise.resolve` is the correct way to work with it (vs. detecting it's a promise clunkily).

It's useful for:

- Working with foreign promises from different libraries.
- Working with values that might be promises and might be plain values.

It's also *implicitly* called a lot with promises.

- When you pass an array of mixed promises, foreign "thenables" and values to `Promise.all` or `Promise.race` - it implicitly `Promise.resolve`s all values.
- Similarly, when you return a foreign "thenable" or a value from `Promise#then(...)` it will call `Promise.resolve` on it.
- When you `await` a value `Promise.resolve` is implicitly called on it.

And so on.

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, `resolve` is basically a lie, because the returned promise is not resolved. It doesn't block execution in the current thread until it finishes. Once an API I need returns a promise, there is no way to force it to execute before returning. Out of 10 or so other times this has been asked, your answer is the first one that comes close to really answering this.

Comment: @coladict `resolve` means "The fate of this promise is resolved by something", the term for a promise "finishing" are fulfilled (successfully) or rejected (unsuccessfully). When you `Promise.reject` (even with another promise you're forcing it into the rejected state (and it's "finished") but there is no way (by design) to make a promise "block" and wait (sorry!) since that wouldn't work well (effectively freezing the web page or node process).

Answer (score 3):

If you have a value that *might be* a Promise, `Promise.resolve` is great.

In the program that I am working on now, I have a lot of places were I create a UI component with callbacks to handle various inputs.  Some times, those callbacks need to return promises, sometimes they don't.  Rather than put the onus on the callback, I always wrap the return value in `Promise.resolve` and boom, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

If `promise1` is really a Promise, then this construct might be used to *convert* from one Promise to another one of a different library, if `Promise` is e.g. defined as `var Promise = require('bluebird');`

It is e.g. useful if you use an older version of jQuery where the Defered object returned from functions did not behave like ES6 conform promises.

Or if you want to use native ES6 Promise with a library like bluebrid that has more features.